# nearest future date from given date and frequency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with start date and frequency of report (every 1 month, 2 months etc.. granularity is one month)

How would I create a select that would, for the actual day, return date of the nearest future report?

```
Example:  
startDate: 15.01.2015, frequency: 3 months  

if today is 03.01.2016 it should return 15.01.2016  
if today is 16.01.2016 it should return 15.04.2016
```

Storing date of last report is not an option.

Edit: Requested sample data and expected result:

```
Actual date is 05.01.2017

StartDate   Freq        Result
02.01.2016  1month      02.02.2017
06.01.2016  1month      06.01.2017
10.03.2016  3months     10.03.2017
01.01.2015  4months     01.05.2017
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar sample data added, let me know if it's not enough

Comment: How many future reports?

Comment: Tip: It would be less confusing if you used ISO date strings: `20150102` is January 2, 2015, regardless of localization.

Comment: @HABO I'll keep that in mind for the next time, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Let play with math.

Calculate the nearest occurrence of an event that happens every M month from some StartDate?

Well, first I calculate the remiander of integer division and modulo, between Month by Frequency just in case MONTH(StartDate) = MONTH(ActualDate)

```
StartDate - ActualDate % Frequency
```

Then I need to know how many times has been fetched the report:

```
Occurrences = StartDate - ActualDate / Frequency
```

Then adding a new occurrence and multiply by the frequency you'll get the number of months you should add to StartDate, taking care when DAY(StartDate) < DAY(ActualDate).

```
(Occurrences + 1) * Frequency = Required month

create table #t (StartDate datetime, Freq varchar(10));
insert into #t values
('2016-01-02','1month'),
('2016-01-06','1month'),
('2016-03-10','3months'),
('2015-01-01','4months'),
('2016-01-06','3month');

DECLARE @ActualDate datetime;
SET @ActualDate = '2017-01-05'

SELECT @ActualDate as ActualDate;

;WITH Calc AS
(
    SELECT StartDate, Freq, CAST(LEFT(Freq, 1) AS Int) as intFreq,
           (DATEDIFF(month, StartDate, @ActualDate) / CAST(LEFT(Freq, 1) AS Int)) AS Occurrences,
           (DATEDIFF(month, StartDate, @ActualDate) % CAST(LEFT(Freq, 1) AS Int)) AS restIntDiv,
           DATEPART(day, StartDate) AS StartDay,
           DATEPART(day, @ActualDate) AS ActDay
    FROM #t
)
SELECT StartDate, Freq,
       CASE WHEN restIntDiv = 0 AND ActDay < StartDay
            THEN DATEADD(month, intFreq * (Occurrences), StartDate)
            ELSE DATEADD(month, intFreq * (Occurrences + 1), StartDate)
       END as [NextReport]
FROM Calc;

+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
|      StartDate      |   Freq  | NextReport          |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 02.01.2016 00:00:00 |  1month | 02.02.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 06.01.2016 00:00:00 |  1month | 06.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 10.03.2016 00:00:00 | 3months | 10.03.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 01.01.2015 00:00:00 | 4months | 01.05.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 06.01.2016 00:00:00 |  3month | 06.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/MBSM51925

Comment: It's not clear how your answer takes `StartDate` from the question into account.

Comment: The original problem is: given a **start date** of January 15, 2015, and  an interval of three months, what will be the next occurrence after the current date. Your code does not appear the calculate whether the next occurrence is in the current month, next month or subsequent month _based on the start date_. It is unlikely to be three months from today unless today is the 15th _and_ happens to be a multiple of three months since the start date.

Comment: Ok, Maybe it can be accomplished without using a  cte, but this way is more clear..

Comment: I think this is it.. I'l be able to properly test it on monday, but this looks very promising - so thank you very much :)

Comment: @McNets just thought I would let you know - it does work perfectly. :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! @quin61

Comment: Just commenting from the future to let you know this piece of code(heavily modified for my own requirements) works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I often use a TVF to create dynamic date/time ranges. A Tally table would do the trick as well.  The UDF is faster than a recursive CTE (especially for larger sets) and offers a bit more functionality.  Date Range, DatePart, and Increments are parameters.

```
Declare @YourTable table (StartDate date,frequency varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-01-02','1month'),
('2016-01-06','1month'),
('2016-03-10','3months'),
('2015-01-01','4months')

Select A.*
      ,NextDate=cast(B.RetVal as date)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top 1 * From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](A.StartDate,'2025-01-15','MM',left(A.frequency,1))
                Where RetVal>=cast(GetDate() as date)
             ) B
```

Returns

```
StartDate   frequency   NextDate
2016-01-02  1month      2017-02-02
2016-01-06  1month      2017-01-06
2016-03-10  3months     2017-03-10
2015-01-01  4months     2017-05-01
```

The UDF if interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```